# Reveal DIV when Checkbox = Checked HTML

Tags: html

I've seen similar questions here, but none have helped. So here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a DIV pertaining to a textbox for a contact email if a user wants to receive a read receipt. I don't want that box to show unless they check the box.

Checkbox:

```
     <p id="notifycheck" class="notify">
    <input id="id_notify" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="notify"/>
    <label for="id_notify">Enable Read Receipts</label>
  </p>
  <div id="notify" class="notify">
    <div id="email_errors">
    </div>
```

Textbox:

```
    <div class="left">
      <p>
        <label for="email_sender">Contact email (suggest Anonmail address)</label>: <br>
        <input id="email_sender" type="text" name="sender_email" size="35" rows="4" maxlength="100"/>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried, and what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple jquery function that detects changes of the input state like this: 
    
                                     `$('#id_notify').on('change',function(){
                                            $('.left').toggleClass('hidden');`

```
    });
});
```

and add in your stylesheet a class of hidden with display:none

Hope this will do